# Rbenv/bundle issue - gems not found in Rack

Tags: ruby, bundler, rack, rbenv

I made the switch from RVM to rbenv and it's plugins. My Gemfile is fine, but when I do `bundle install`, `rbenv rehash` etc. and run `rack <whatever>` it doesn't find any of the gems. See below. Anyone have any thoughts?

```
Vanessas-MacBook-Pro:my-app vanessa$ rbenv versions
* 1.8.7-p352 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
  1.9.2-p290
  1.9.3-rc1
  rbx-1.2.4
Vanessas-MacBook-Pro:my-app vanessa$ rbenv version
1.8.7-p352 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
Vanessas-MacBook-Pro:my-app vanessa$ more Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem "sinatra"
gem "god"
gem "rack", '1.2.3'
gem "activemodel", "~>3.0"


group :test do
  gem "rake"
end
Vanessas-MacBook-Pro:my-app vanessa$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.21)
rake (0.9.2.2)
redgreen (1.2.2)
rubygems-update (1.8.11)
Vanessas-MacBook-Pro:my-app vanessa$ rake test
/Users/vanessa/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby -I"lib:lib:test" -I"/Users/vanessa/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib" "/Users/vanessa/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/**/test_*.rb" 
/Users/vanessa/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rack/test (LoadError)
    from /Users/vanessa/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    ...
    ...
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/vanessa/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/bin/...]

Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Vanessas-MacBook-Pro:my-app vanessa$
```

Comment: what happens if you delete Gemfile.lock and do again bundle, rbenv rehash ?

Answer (score 4):

use bundle exec

```
bundle exec rake test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'rack-test' to your Gemfile.